# Why can we supply a Comparator to TreeSet but not something like Hasher to HashSet?

Tags: java, hashset, treeset

In Java 6, my understanding is that you can supply a Comparator to a TreeSet when creating it to override the "natural ordering" of the objects in the set.

Do you have any thoughts why Java doesn't support supplying a "Hasher" that overrides the "natural hashing" of objects in the set as well?

EDIT: 
Getting input from you might help me when designing APIs in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: The API is what it is. Asking "why" can only ever be speculation.

Comment: You could ask the same question for Set and equals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several likely reasons:

- **Simplicity** - most people don't need multiple hash functions, so to keep the API simple it makes sense to rely on a single Object.hashCode() approach
- **Performance** - In the standard library at least,
  HashSets and HashMaps etc. need to be
  pretty heavily optimised as they are
  so widely used. It doesn't make sense
  to have the overhead of calling a
  separate "hasher", however small that
  overhead may be.
- **Private fields** - there is the issue that
  hashCode() may rely on private
  fields, it may be difficult to
  create external "hashers" for some
  objects.

Answer (score 2):

**A `Hasher` object would be redundant to the `hashCode()` method in the `Object` class.**

If you want to effect the nature of the hashing, you should override the `hashCode()` method defined on `Object`.  Just be sure to override `equals(Object)` as well, since these two should always go together.

A `HashSet` or other similar data structure will use the objects `hashCode()` method to get a hash value to determine bin storage.  It will then use `equals()` to compare that object to other objects in the same bin to determine equality.

The hash code generated needs to be unique to that specific class of object.  This can be ensured simply by overriding the `hashCode()` method and doesn't need to change from implementation to implementation.  A `Hasher` object would just obfuscate and serve no additional purpose.  I couldn't think of a single use case where multiple hash codes would be needed for storage in different data structures.

Comment: Absolutely correct, and your input to why there's a Comparator and not a Hasher is?

Comment: You don't need a `Hasher` when there's a `hashCode()` method on `Object` that does it already.  If `Object` had a `compareTo()` method on it, then you wouldn't need a `Comparator`.

Comment: You DO need a Comparator if you want to override the natural ordering, but I see where you're coming from. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It does! Check out the [Object.hashCode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29.) method.

After reading your question again I might have jumped the gun. I now see that you said "override" the natural hshing. Usually we override the hash value at the object level and forgo the use of a overriding Hasher.

Hashes are meant to be more universal that comparators. That is, hashes should almost always create uniform distrusted values with little chance of collision. The container in which they are used should rarely need a specialized hasher.

Comment: You came back to answer the question! +1 for that :)

Answer (score 1):

[It has already been asked.](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6435963)

Comment: Good stuff! Next time I'll have to consult Sun's bugs database before asking something here.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the hash code of an object by wrapping in an Object which inplements hash code your way.  The assumption is that you may want to have a objects sorted a numebr of ways, but not have multiple hashing strategies.

c.f. Trove4j supports hashing strategies for its HashMap and while I use this library often I have only used a custom hashing strategy once I can remember.